# Baseline website user survey, standard vs. custom questions?

Tags: usability, wording, surveys

I am planning on doing a baseline user survey this holiday season to assess where we are at before starting the entire user experience tests and study.

I think the following questions are a good starting point (baseline) for our entire UX study. I have had one stakeholder express that the questions are too generic and will not really produce good enough results.

I have used these same questions for a baseline test at my previous post and would like to know if anyone else uses these questions or similar ones. Thanks.

[Look at my survey preview](https://www.surveymonkey.com/create/survey/preview?r=true&sm=c47KxnfUY_2FsU5aPG7zUCYWJLhS_2FOA9S7N3pMeMntaT8Guc_2F0ifPdIFJiifbigQLyp1aoUKE2YX775Rh0AQThZg_3D_3D)

Comment: Suggestion for improving the answers: use a Likert scale or a slider instead of a dropdown.

Comment: Thanks for the responses! I will go ahead and change it to the Likert scale and will consider the question ordering and rewording from below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that to sharpen the focus on question 8 ("How long did it take to find what you were looking for?") and use phrasing more like "When you were looking for something, how long did it take you?" I would move the current question 8 immediately after question 4 to give the survey respondent context for their answer.

I would then reduce the number of possible answers for this question from 6 to 4 - removing choices that are difficult to discriminate (e.g. "A lot less time" and "A little less time").  Often when I am performing user testing I will use a Likert scale that includes 5 items (on a scale of, for example, 0 to 4). I find it's easier for users to respond to fewer items on the scale - especially if there are many questions as part of the testing.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the survey based on some talks I had with some stakeholders and also considering what was posted on this question. Here is the most current version.

[Here is the updated survey*](https://www.surveymonkey.com/create/survey/preview?r=true&sm=c47KxnfUY_2FsU5aPG7zUCYWJLhS_2FOA9S7N3pMeMntaT8Guc_2F0ifPdIFJiifbigQLyp1aoUKE2YX775Rh0AQThZg_3D_3D)